# Cron job from cpanel.. no success

Tags: cron, cpanel, unix

I tried a lot of methods but ended up with nothing in hand..My simple target is to reset a variable to zero at the end of the day.

i checked the location of php as "which php" and "whereis php"

which resulted into /usr/bin/php

here are some of things i tried..

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/USERNAME/public_html/developer3/crons/filename.php

/usr/bin/php -f /home/USERNAME/public_html/developer3/crons/filename.php

php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/developer3/crons/filaname.php

/usr/bin/wget -O http://subdomain.sitename.com/crons/filename.php
```

for quick results, i kept the timming as every minute to execute the code. i could successfully execute the code as

```
http://subdomain.sitename.com/crons/filename.php
```

please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to php on your system is /usr/bin/php then the command you should be running with cron should be

```
/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/php/script.php
```

Is the script you're running designed to be invoked from the php-cli in that way? If it isn't and works correctly when you use a browser then you can use curl, if it's installed on your server

curl -A cron-job http://subdomain.sitename.com/crons/filename.php

It would likely be helpful in any event to configure the MAILTO variable (since you're using cPanel, it's just a text box on the appropriate page that you can fill in) so that you get an email with the output from your cron jobs. Having the output emailed to you will help you diagnose what's causing your script to not have the desired effect when it runs.

Comment: still no success, is there any mistake in any of the lines of codes i've posted above in original question, no email is received, no error message, moreover ..how do i confirm if curl is installed in cpanel or not..

Comment: this is just for notification..
following code somehow worked..

/usr/bin/wget -O- http://subdomain.sitename.com/crons/filename.php